# On algrithms that minimizes maximal load of bins

Tags: algorithm

There are `n` bins and `m` balls. Balls are with different weights, say ball `i` has weight `w_i`. Is there an algorithm that assigns balls into `x<n` bins so that maximal load of these bins is minimized.

Comment: This question belongs on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com, but there are already plenty of packing questions there, so I won't migrate it. Instead, I will close it as off-topic, and kindly ask you to review the questions already on that site, and see if any of them happens to answer your question. Here's a search link: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/search?q=packing

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to the [multiprocessor scheduling problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessor_scheduling), which is NP-complete. In other words: algorithm(s) exist, but they are very slow.

Comment: Aasmund pretty much gets this one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a disguised hash function question.  i.e. You are looking for an optimal hash function.   Check out this page - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Generally you want a random key that you can XOR with w_i then take the result mod n to get the bin number.

Note: I took maximal load to mean number of balls per bin.  Hashing of course does not work if you want to minimize the weight of each bin.

Comment: He's not interested in an even distribution of the _number_ of balls (which is what an optimal hash function would give), but an even distribution of the _weight_.

Comment: I believe you’re wrong, Aasmund has the correct answer. I don’t see how this problem relates to hashing except for the fact that of course the resulting mapping can be expressed as a hash function (but that’s trivial, and not very interesting).

Comment: btw - We haven't actually 'solved' the problem, but optimal solutions to np-complete problems are fairly easy to describe; run through every possible combination of balls to bins and see which gives the best result :-)